# ArrayList of Files

Tags: java, arraylist

I am having trouble creating an ArrayList of files...

I am trying to have a collection of  text files which I can then process. I do not know the amount of files that may be added to this collection.

This is what I am trying...

```
public class Main {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Menu");
    System.out.println("Add - Adds a file");
    while (sc.next().equalsIgnoreCase("Add")) {
        getDocs();
    }
}
  public static void getDocs() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<File> allFiles = new ArrayList<>();
    allFiles.add(new File(sc.nextLine()));
    System.out.println(allFiles.toString());
}
```

The println will only show the most recent file added to the ArrayList, and it also doesn't show the text in the file,so I assume my arrayList is not functioning as I want...

the output I expected would be...

```
Menu
Add- adds a file

add
C://somepath//file1

This is the text in file 1

add

C://somepath//file2

This is the text in file 1
This is the text in file 2
```

though, all that is really important is that all of these files are in a collection, and I can pull and read those files later in the program. 
Thanks for taking a look

Comment: You want to add files too a collection that the user types in? And there is no place for a dialog box or something in this? Do you need to check if the file is a valid file or are you just assuming what the user is giving you is correct?

Comment: Hehe, first of all, toString() just prints a hex code of your object. If you want for example to show content of file, you should have your own toString() overrided version which will print file content. So you should have a wrapper class which will wrap the file (one by one) and simple have toString() method to print it's value. ArrayList should contain Wrapper classes instead.

Comment: @energizer - no it doesn't ... toString() prints whatever the classes implementation wants to print. The _default_ `Object.toString()` prints the address of your object, but ArrayList overrides that and prints a comma-separated list of its contents. You can't make (many) general statements about toString.

Comment: The location doesn't need to be checked for validity, this is for personal use only.

Comment: And thank you for your comments, especially about toSting() I really should have read the method description in netbeans before assuming it's function >.< anyway, my answer has been found and the programming can continue! Thank you for your help everyone

Comment: @energizer - ... and `File` class has its own `toString()` method as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`allFiles` should be a class member variable rather than a local variable of `getDocs` method

Try this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().menu();
    }

    ArrayList<File> allFiles = new ArrayList<>();

    public void menu() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Menu");
        System.out.println("Add - Adds a file");

        while (sc.next().equalsIgnoreCase("Add")) {
            getDocs();
        }
    }

    public void getDocs() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        allFiles.add(new File(sc.nextLine()));
        System.out.println(allFiles.toString());
    }
}
```

Also, `File#toString` method gives you the file name not the file contents.  You would actually have to do some extra steps to read and output the file if that's what you want.

Answer (score 4):

You have

```
ArrayList<File> allFiles = new ArrayList<>();
```

in `getDocs()` method.

This declaration makes it a `local` variable.  Your list needs to be declared and initialized as a `class` variable (outside all methods) and then just used in `getDocs()`

Answer (score 0):

With `allFiles.toString()` you are printing the string representation of your `ArrayList`.

You need to iterate the files on the array list, open them and then print their contents.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in simple manner.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<File> allFiles = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Menu");
        System.out.println("Add - Adds a file");
        while (sc.next().equalsIgnoreCase("Add")) {
            getDocs(allFiles);
        }
        System.out.println(allFiles.toString());
    }
    public static void getDocs(List<File> files) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        files.add(new File(sc.nextLine()));
    }
```

Comment: Why on earth, would you need to create a new `Scanner` object for *each* file added?